# A very quick way to prove a set is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, axiom-of-choice

All examples of non-measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (in the Lebesgue sense) seem to need the axiom of choice in some way or the other. Hence, can we say:

> The set $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is measurable because the axiom of choice was not used to define it.

Is that a valid argument? Or does there exist non-measurable sets that do not require the axiom of choice?

Comment: I suspect it might be hard to prove that you never used choice in your definition. Also, you can use choice to define measurable sets.

Comment: You don't need the full strength of the axiom of choice. You could limit the choice axiom to collections that have at most $c$ sets.

Comment: @yyyyyyy I disagree that this is a duplicate. I read the nice answer by AsafKaragila but I am still puzzled about my question of whether this can be used as a proof that a set is measurable.

Comment: See also [Axiom of choice and non measurable set](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73902)